# ambiguity over information returned by GoogleMaps Elevation Api

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, maps, elevation

I want to ask whether the value returned by google maps' elevation api is the height of the ground-surface from the sea level? So, if there is a foot over bridge or an elevated road would the api return the elevation of the ground or of the structure built on the ground(elevated road in this case)?

How and where may I get information related to elevations of such man made structures(bridges) which are not on ground level, rather at an elevation?

Comment: "The [Google Maps Elevation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/intro#What) provides elevation data for all locations on the surface of the earth, including depth locations on the ocean floor (which return negative values). In those cases where Google does not possess exact elevation measurements at the precise location you request, the service will interpolate and return an averaged value using the four nearest locations.". As quoted, the zero elevation is at sea level so anything higher than sea-level would return a positive value and negative otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. To be more precise, if the ground is at an elevation 'a' meters from the sea level at location(x,y) and the bridge is 'b' meters from the ground at (x,y), the value provided by @Google Maps Elevation API  at (x,y) would be 'a+b' or 'a' is what I would like to know. Any help would be appreciated